# Continue from Label Error

Tags: java, loops

I am programming a simulated online banking client in java. I need the ability (or an alternative) to be able to continue from a label. This is a snippet from my code so far.

```
    Main:
    {
    for ( ; ;) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Tamarin© online banking!");
    System.out.println("Select register or login:");

    choice = scan.nextLine();

    if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("register")) {
        register:
        {
        System.out.println("Welcome to register! Please type your username:");
        userreg = scan.nextLine();

        if (accounts.contains(userreg)) {
            System.out.println("Username taken! Try again.");
            continue register;
```

Java is giving me a "continue cannot be used outside of loop" error. Any ideas as to (if the registration fails) I could bring the user back to the last step ('registration' label)? And if not, how could I get this code to work?

(I obviously have closing braces down at the end).

Comment: Do  ot work with labels in java

Comment: Continue an iteration can't happen outside of something iterable. Use a loop to continually prompt and break on success

Answer (score 0):

Well you shouldn't be using a `goto` in the first place (which currently doesn't exist in Java), the reason for this being that using labels promotes badly structured and difficult to maintain code (also called *spaghetti code*).

Instead you should add a `nameTaken` boolean and loop while it is true.

```
while(nameTaken) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to register! Please type your username:");
    userreg = scan.nextLine();

    if (accounts.contains(userreg))
        System.out.println("Username taken! Try again.");
    else {
        // do stuff
        nameTaken = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks for using labels and taking us all back to C programming from so long ago.  Second, you can easily simulate the behavior you currently have with labels by using appropriately constructed loops, e.g.

```
do {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Tamarin© online banking!");
    System.out.println("Select register or login:");
    choice = scan.nextLine();

    if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("register")) {
        do {
            System.out.println("Welcome to register! Please type your username:");
            userreg = scan.nextLine();

            if (!accounts.contains(userreg)) {
                System.out.println("Creating username " + userreg + " ...");
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Username taken! Try again.");
            }
        } while (true);
    }

    // the rest of your logic goes here
} while (true);
```